# how to send data to url with POST Method in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, post, nsurlconnection

I want to send one data with `POST` method to one url and received answer from that url.
I write this code for send data ("**a**") to this url ("**http://www.test.com/test/msht**")

this is my code but not working please guide me how to send data and give answer from url.

```
-(IBAction)btn_post_clicked:(id)sender{

    //if there is a connection going on just cancel it.
    [self.connection cancel];

    //initialize new mutable data
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    self.receivedData = data;
    [data release];

    //initialize url that is going to be fetched.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.com/test/msht"];

    //initialize a request from url
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];

    //set http method
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //initialize a post data
    NSString *postData = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"a"];
    //set request content type we MUST set this value.

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    //set post data of request
    [request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //initialize a connection from request
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    self.connection = connection;
    [connection release];

    //start the connection
    [connection start];


}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"%@" , error);
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    //initialize convert the received data to string with UTF8 encoding
    NSString *htmlSTR = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@" , htmlSTR);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend your code is wrong!!! you should determine name of post value in post NSString....
you don't send **a** value only.

you should write this code if get post method name in server is **user** :

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user=a"];
```